# Using a BroadcastReceiver to update a ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-progressbar

I am trying to update a `ProgressBar` from a `Service` task. I implemented a `BroadcastReceiver` so that I can interact with the UI thread. I update the `ProgressBar` in the main activity, and receive the data from the MyService activity. The MyService activity executes an Async task and updates the intent that should be sent back in the OnProgressUpdate method.

> Here is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.services;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyBroadRequestReceiver receiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
        receiver = new MyBroadRequestReceiver();
        registerReceiver( receiver, filter);
    }

    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
        //pb.setProgress();
    }
    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
    public class MyBroadRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            int progress = intent.getFlags();
            pb.setProgress(progress);

        }

    }
}
```

**MyService:**

```
package com.example.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyService extends Service {

    int counter = 0;
    static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        doSomethingRepeatedly();

        try {
            new DoBackgroundTask().execute(
                    new URL("http://www.amazon.com/somefiles.pdf"),
                    new URL("http://www.wrox.com/somefiles.pdf"),
                    new URL("http://www.google.com/somefiles.pdf"),
                    new URL("http://www.learn2develop.net/somefiles.pdf"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void doSomethingRepeatedly() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("MyService", String.valueOf(++counter));

            }
        }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    }

    private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            int count = urls.length;
            long totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                totalBytesDownloaded += DownloadFile(urls[i]);
                //Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                //broadcastIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                //sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                publishProgress((int) (((i + 1) / (float) count) * 100));
            }
            return totalBytesDownloaded;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            Log.d("Downloading files", String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "% downloaded");
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.services.MainActivity");
            //broadcastIntent.putExtra("progress",progress);
            broadcastIntent.setFlags(progress[0]);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "% downloaded-"+counter,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Downloaded " + result + " bytes",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //stopSelf();
        }
    }

    private int DownloadFile(URL url) {
        try {
            //---simulate taking some time to download a file---
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //---return an arbitrary number representing
        // the size of the file downloaded---
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Please take a look at my `onProgressUpdate` and tell me if I am doing this correclty. My ProgressBar is not being updated at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because  you don't  startService ononCreate() Method. Service  will  not  run.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all this is not good solution to the problem your solving. Please go through Google Android docs [Backgournd guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)

I suggest you should switch to DownloadManager.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent filter is defining to "ACTION_ATTACH_DATA"

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
```

So, send your broadcast like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Also, don't forget to unregister the broadcast at onDestroy